# Is there a more efficient way to use the Linq Last() command?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a huge PostgresDB machine data table (with TimeScale) and need to get the the last position of a machine. I know, the most efficient way would be a continuous aggregation each day with timescale and and save the last position. But that's not the point of this Question ;)

So, I'm using Linq to do the SQL Request. I have tried some different Method to get the Last Position of the Machine, which I now explain below. I have to mention that the Duration of each function is that huge, because I'm testing it with a list of 60 machine.

1. LINQ function **last()** -> Duration: 132s / Needs a lot of RAM because Last() is calculating outside of the Database. There is a huge data transfer between Database and Program because LINQ can't translate Last() to SQL.

   ```csharp
   gpsPositionDto.Latitude = _context.MeasureValues.Last(c => c.MachineId == machine && c.MeasureValueId == 80).Value;
   ```
2. LINQ function **OrderByDescending().First()** -> Duration: 114s / Database is needing RAM because the calculation is done inside the Database. So there is no huge data transfer between the Database and Program.

   ```csharp
   gpsPositionDto.Latitude = _context.MeasureValues.OrderByDescending(c => c.Timestamp).First(c => c.MachineId == machine && c.MeasureValueId == 80).Value;
   ```
3. LINQ function **first()** -> Duration: 30s / I know, this don't give me the right Value, but I wanted to try it out to see how long this needs.

   ```csharp
   gpsPositionDto.Latitude = _context.MeasureValues.First(c => c.MachineId == machine && c.MeasureValueId == 80).Value;
   ```

Is there any possibility to get a similar Duration to first(), but that I get the correct Data? Because I will execute this function once an Hour for further calculation and we get more and more Machine's inside this List.

Comment: Do you have a compound index on MachineId/MeasureValueId/Timestamp ?

Comment: ... a compound index on MachineId  and MeasureValueId should be sufficient

Comment: Avoid Linq and call a sproc directly to get that information.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? Have you looked at the SQL generated for your LINQ queries? 60 machines doesn't seem like a lot: how many rows are in the table(s)?

Comment: @NetMage It's a timeseries Table. At the moment there are around 300 Machine inside this table, but I'm using 60 of them to do some further calculation. The hole table has around 2 Billion Datapoint at the moment. All Data older then 15 Days are compressed with the Timescale Compression.
So, we are using EF Core 2.1 but at the moment we are working to upgrade the whole system to EF6

Answer (score 2):

```
gpsPositionDto.Latitude = 
      _context.MeasureValues
              .Last(c => c.MachineId == machine && c.MeasureValueId == 80).Value;
```

This doesn't really have a meaning.  Without an `OrderBy`, "First" and "Last" has no meaning. I tried replicating use cases using the Northwind database on Microsoft SQL Express.  It wouldn't even let me do a `.Last()` on a table.

```
Orders.Last(o=>o.CustomerID == "TOMSP")
```

"NotSupportedException•••
The query operator 'Last' is not supported."

Your option 2 worked fine:

```
Orders.OrderByDescending(o =>o.OrderDate ).First(o=>o.CustomerID == "TOMSP")
```

generating this SQL:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'TOMSP'
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP(1)[t0].[OrderID], [t0].[CustomerID],
             [t0].[EmployeeID], [t0].[OrderDate], 
             [t0].[ShipPostalCode], [t0].[ShipCountry]
FROM[Orders] AS[t0]
WHERE [t0].[CustomerID] = @p0
ORDER BY[t0].[OrderDate] DESC
```

It's possible that, for Option 1, Postgres is effective doing:

```
Orders.ToList().Last(o=>o.CustomerID == "TOMSP")
```

reading the entire table into memory, and then searching on it there, which could explain the bad timings for that.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the easiest solution at the moment. But i will probably do a Timescale continuous aggregation and picking the Data from the new Table. Then I'm saving a lot of RAM and calculation power. By the way, thank you for that answer